# Multiline sublime text language module definition

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I'm trying to create a new syntax definition for Sublime Text. I've worked out the regular expression to highlight a match within a each line but I'd like the match to include new lines as well as any character. Here's the regex from the tmLanguage file that works within a single line:

```
<key>match</key>
<string>\{\+\+(.*?)\+\+[ \t]*(\[(.*?)\])?[ \t]*\}</string>
```

I've attempted to modify the the dot (.) matching to span multilines but it doesn't actually appear to capture the entire block. My understanding is that the modifier ?m: should work, but does not.

```
<key>match</key>
<string>(?m:(\{\+\+(.*?)\+\+[ \t]*(\[(.*?)\])?[ \t]*\}))</string>
```

Is there a way to declare a language definition regex that will match across multiple lines?

Comment: I don't think that would give the right match but I did try it anyway. No luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the single-line modifier instead :

```
<key>match</key>
<string>(?s:(\{\+\+(.*?)\+\+[ \t]*(\[(.*?)\])?[ \t]*\}))</string>
```

You're misunderstanding the `(?m)` modifier.
**Your regex is always applied on a single line.**

- Using the multi-line modifier means your regex will consider your text as several lines (which is the default behavior), then it'll add `^(...)$` around each line.
- Using the single-line modifier, `^(...)$` won't be added, and then `.` will match `\r\n`